# How do I host the backend of Phonegap app?

Tags: sqlite, firebase, phonegap-build, phonegap, phpbb

I am building a cross-platform mobile app for iOS and Android using PhoneGap and I am confused about how to host the backend. The app will have user accounts and a forum (implemented using PHPbb) so data needs to be shared across devices.

Through my research I have found the SQLite plugin for PhoneGap apps, and I know that PHPbb can sit on top of an SQLite database, but I am confused on two things:

- Can I implement user accounts using SQLite as it is not a client/sever database?
- If yes, is it possible to host an SQLite database using a BAAS solution like Firebase that my PhoneGap app can talk to using the SQLite plugin, and will it be compatible with PhoneGap build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has realtime database and firestore database options. There is no SQLite option. Google Cloud Platform offers CloudSQL which allows for postgreSQL and mysql options.

Firebase hosting is designed to help you host your own custom functions and application backends. PHPBB requires PHP support (among other things) and firebase functions only support nodejs.

If you are looking to host an app like phpbb, look into launching a phpbb VM on google cloud platform as an option. https://bitnami.com/stack/phpbb/cloud/google

Firebase authentication is designed to allow you to support user accounts for a custom app backend.

How you decide to tie your app into phpbb will probably have nothing to do with firebase.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Do you know if it would be possible to do user authentication through Firebase and and host phpbb separately on the Google Cloud Platform and integrate both of these with a PhoneGap app?

Comment: @LucyWalsh, I would take a look at this for authentication https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova
I'm not sure the status of phpbb's rest api: https://wiki.phpbb.com/REST_API. How to tie all these together I don't have experience with unfortunately. I might suggest re-evaluating the functionality you really need and whether these are the best tools to combine.

Comment: Thanks again for your help and clarification Matthew - you were right that I should re-evaluate the tools, and I've gone with a PostgreSQL hosted on AWS as the backend which is working a treat so far.